# How to force variable to be public kotlin

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin

i have the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`users`")
class User(
    var name: String,
    var avatar: ByteArray
) {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1


    fun getAvatarAsImage(): BufferedImage? {
        val img: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(avatar)
        return ImageIO.read(img)
    }

    fun setAvatarAsImage(img: BufferedImage) {
        val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", out)
        avatar = out.toByteArray()
    }

}
```

but hibernate says that id is private (thats because kotlin auto-generating getters and setters),
so compiled to java it seems like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
   strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
)
private long id;

public long getId() {
   return this.id;
}

public void setId(long var1) {
   this.id = var1;
}
```

QUESTION: how to make it compiled like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
   strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
)
public long id;
```

???

idk what is this....

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message to your question? Hibernate (and JPA in general) should work just fine with private fields, especially in non-modular contexts (by "non-modular" I mean no `module-info` descriptor).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have interpreted the error message from Hibernate properly, as the `@Id`-annotation seems correct. But I'm wondering if you perhaps forgot to use the kotlin-jpa compiler plugin that helps creating Hibernate-friendly classes?

Read more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html#jpa-support

Maybe you can try putting the annotations on the getter instead to force Hibernate to use property-based access... Try modifying the annotations to:

```
@get:Id
@get:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
var id: Long = -1
```

... or even worst case expose the field as public (as you are asking for) with...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JvmField
var id: Long = -1
```

Comment: yes, im using kotlin jpa